# How can i keep track of String values?

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans, while-loop

I'm building some kind of game for programming class and I need to have a history of the people who played, you can play multiple times when you run the game, so I'm not trying to store it permanently just when the game is executing.

I was thinking maybe some kind of array or something that can store all the string variables (names), but I don't how to do this indefinitely until the game stops.

Also, I am **not** allowed use java data structures (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.)
.

Alternatively, if this is not possible or very complicated, maybe some way to store the names of only the last 10 people that play would work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If storing the last 10 people would be sufficient, why not just do that.  Start with a 10-element array and a count of the number of people in it.  To add a new player: if less than 10 already in the array, put the player in the next available slot (i.e., the one pointed to by your count) and bump the count; if already full, move everybody in slots 9 thru 1 down to slots 8 thru 0 (thus effectively "forgetting" whoever was already at slot 0) and put the new person at slot 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data structures are not allowed, you could actually just make do of a comma-delimited String because an array in order to initialize you need to specify its size already (but this is something you definitely cannot know yet).  Have a static instance of the String, then append to it a delimiter (comma) and the the player name.

```
private static String commaDelimitedStr = "";

public void addPlayerName (String playerName) {
commaDelimitedStr = commaDelimitedStr.concat(",").concat(playerName);
}
```

Then at the end you can split the String to get an array version of it.

```
String[] names = commaDelimitedStr.split(",");
```